# Output and bitcoin spent what does it mean? I need help

Tags: bitcoin-cash

[image]
Hope you are doing well, I'm new to bitcoin. Please does this mean I received $61.213.88 in my account? Or the total output of all my transactions it shows 2 bitcoin addresses under, what does "spent" mean? And all the addresses are invalid when I look them up. THANKS

Comment: To provide any help, you’ll need to offer up more info. How are you associated with this transaction? Do you expect to receive this amount of BTC? Which addresses do you own (have the private key for)? Etc

Answer (score 1):

This transaction just means that, some time in the past, someone transferred an amount of Bitcoin (BTC) to two recipients, one was probably a second person providing goods or services to the first person, the other recipient was probably change being returned to the first person.

The amount of Bitcoin was roughly equivalent to $61,000 at some point in time.

Both the recipients subsequently spent the received amounts in further transactions.

It is possible that either or both recipients now control 0 Bitcoin.

It is possible that either or both recipients now control millions of Bitcoin.

Only the recipients can tell for sure. Their Bitcoin wallets will tell them.

---

Let's say B is new to Bitcoin and wants to buy some for 150 Canadian dollars. B meets a millionaire A who is willing to sell some. B gives A the 150 Canadian dollars. A does the Bitcoin equivalent of reaching into their back pocket and taking out a crocodile-skin wallet. A looks inside sees seven $1000000 banknotes and a $61,234.56 banknote∆. A gives B the $61,234.56 banknote and B then gives A a $61,134.56 banknote in change. B now has $100 more, A has $100 less.

A and B then immediately spent all their  money on a superyacht and a pair of trainers and are now broke.

Or maybe not.

∆ Such things exist in the cryptocurrency world.